# Where is WebKitErrors.h?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm trying to #include WebKitError.h to access its constants, but either of these lines generates a file not found compilation error

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKitErrors.h>
```

Location taken from googling and from here
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Miscellaneous/WebKit_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003839

Comment: Try this (added "s" to WebKitError) #import <WebKit/WebKitErrors.h>

Comment: That's what I tried, it was a typo in my question, not in my code.

Comment: Ok, do you have the Webkit framework added to your project also?

Comment: I also get a message that says `<WebKit/WebKitErrors.h>` isn't found, and I definitely have WebKit.framework in my "Link binary with libraries" section of my Build phases. (fwiw, `<WebKit/WebKit.h>` is found, but doesn't include declarations for the web kit errors)